# Vokoscreen NG hotkeys do not work on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Installed VokoscreenNG 3.0.9 on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. The hotkeys (like Ctrl+Shift+F10 to start recording) work on Ubuntu, but not on Windows. A web search did not turn up any clues. Vokoscreen does not seem to have any settings to change the hotkeys. The keyboard keys Ctrl, Shift work for moving cursor, selecting text etc. I do not know how to test F10.

My programming skills are too limited to edit the Vokoscreen source code on Github.

Is there some setting in Windows that would disable a program's hotkeys? Any other ideas to point my web search in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The F1-F12 keys only work if simultaneously pressing fn, otherwise they default to the white symbols on them, like Mute, Print screen, Home. Such a simple thing I did not figure out for hours.

It would still be nice to be able to change Vokoscreen's hotkeys. This option is available in OBS Studio.